# The const modifier in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

1, Please see the following code:

```
const UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
view.tag = 2;
```

2,In my mind, the "const" meaning the variable can't be changed.
3, So I think I can't change the content of the object which "view" point to,but I can change the view.tag, I don't know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct usage would be `UIView *const view = [[UIView alloc] init];`

You can't change the content of `view` but you can always change the content of the object which `view` holds

Rest is explained in this question : [What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1143262/468724)

Why you are able to change the `tag` is because it is defined as

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger tag; // default is 0
```

It's not defined as constant(readonly) thus you are able to change its `tag`. If you want that content of the object should not change then in that case you have to change the definition of that class and make their ivar as `const` or `readonly` in case of properties.

Comment: 1,Actually, I think there is no approach to change the content of the object.

Comment: I can change the pointer or the content the object holds only.